# What material does latex grammar allow in front of documentclass

Tags: sourcecode

I have written software to typeset latex documents in a folder and subfolders.
To that end, I have to recognize latex main files, i.e. TEX files which are documents,
as opposed to TEX files which are included/input into other TEX-files.

So far i recognize latex main files by the keyword `documentclass`.
Of course i don't want to scan the whole file
as it typically comes quite at the beginning.
Besides comments and `\RequirePackage` commands,
also `\newbool` and `\setbool` seem to be allowed.
What are the precise restrictions on the allowed material?

I am aware that this may be a difficult question.

Comment: Everything is allowed that doesn't result in typeset output, and that doesn't use a few specific macros like `\usepackage` (for which there is the alternative `\RequirePackage`), but one can make arbitrary redefinitions of things such that also `\usepackage` would work... So just scan the file for `\documentclass` and hope for the best (even a `\documentclass` could be part of a file without that file being the main file).

Comment: If you make the latex files, what prevents you to start  every file with a comment like `% main file` or `% subdocument` and check only that comment in the first line?

Comment: there is no grammar, but anything other than RequirePackage is rather unusual

Comment: @DavidCarlisle a few definitions could also end up there like some `\newcommand` (some packages have such mechanisms to control their behaviour, and those might be required by the `\documentclass`).

Comment: @Skillmon oh sure and also `\PassOptionsToPackage` I have documents which change the catcode regime but ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and filecontents  (and \DocumentMetadata ;-)).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ooh you are so modern